# WPF multicolumn listbox performance while scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

How can I create a multicolumn ListView/ListBox in WPF with good performance. I know how to do it with WrapPanel. In the ListBox I have about 70-150 items and scrolling is laggy/not so fluent (like with VirtualStackPanel). Do you know how to solve this problem? 
Thank you

Here is ListBox XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxSubtitles" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"   Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Subtitle,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FFEEECEC"
                >
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="520" Height="150" Background="#FF424242" Margin="5,5,5,0">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="85"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding PosterImgUri,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                            <Image.Effect>
                                <BlurEffect Radius="40" />
                            </Image.Effect>
                        </Image>
                        <Image Width="75" Height="110" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2,2,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="{Binding PosterImgUri,Mode=TwoWay}" Stretch="Fill"/>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="86%" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold">
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SubtitleName,Mode=TwoWay}">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Label>
                            <Grid>
                                <Label Content="Stažení:"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="18"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding subtitleName,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="65,-7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="18"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Width="100" Height="20" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <ProgressBar Value="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="7,0,0,0"   Foreground="#FF84E60F" Background="White"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,-2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="50" FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>


                    </Grid>



    </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

also I would like to ask, how to remove this blue selection when mouse is focusing item. [image: Item with blue selection background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a virtualizing wrap panel. Unfortunately, writing such kind of panel is not easy and most good implementations are either not free or not working for arbitrary complex data templates.

You can make the image bindings async, using the IsAsync property.

Another approach is to reduce the visual tree, which is not an option, because you go after quality. You can move the layout from the DataTemplate into a dedicated UserControl and load the images only when the control is visible (VisibilityChanged event or rectangle intersect based).